# Next.js app with both Javascript and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I have a Next.js app written in Javascript, and planning on starting to write new code in Typescript.
I tried adding Typescript to the project by running `touch tsconfig.json` at the project root And

`npm install --save-dev typescript @types/react @types/node`

And when I try to run `npm run dev` I get an error

```
error - ./pages/_app.js:6:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'src/assets/styles/index.scss'
```

And pretty much all modules cannot be imported.

What do I need to configure in order to work with both Javascript and Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Stopping and restarting the server should fix most of your module import issues.

SCSS should be ready to go but if it continues after the restart, declaring it in a typescript declaration file should resolve it.

```
// index.d.ts
declare module '*.scss';
```

Comment: I tried both restarting the server and adding the ```index.d.ts``` as suggested. Still getting the same error. It seems the issue is not just with scss modules

Answer (score 0):

Adding to `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    ...
}
```

Resolved this